# Geopandas error message during installation

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying install geopandas. I have using codes I can't find but i keep getting error messages. I have `geopy` already installed but can't install `geopandas`.

Result i had when running installation with anaconda prompt:

[image]

I had also tried installation using `%pip install geopandas --user`

```
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (962 kB)
Collecting pyproj>=2.2.0
  Using cached pyproj-2.6.1.post1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (15.7 MB)
Collecting shapely
  Using cached Shapely-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (894 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23.0 in c:\users\fejiro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geopandas) (1.0.5)
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.17.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\fejiro\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\fejiro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q86d5ghj\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\fejiro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q86d5ghj\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\fejiro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-64u_nnsk'
         cwd: C:\Users\fejiro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q86d5ghj\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can someone tell what to do?

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems that you were trying to install the package in the base/root environment. Don't do that! It's best to always create a separate environment for each application/project. It's almost certainly the cause of the first error.

Comment: thanks for your response. How can i create a new environment?

Comment: Finally fixed by after finding a way to install a new environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It s better to use Anaconda distribution for more complex packages. Use install anaconda and then create an environment for the project. After that, you could use `conda-forge` to take care of all the compatibility problems

Comment: OK. thanks for your response. How can i create a new environment?

Comment: Finally fixed by after finding a way to install a new environment

Comment: What's the point of downloading Anaconda if you're going to get almost all the packages from conda-forge?

Comment: can you use conda-forge without Anaconda?